# Python Service with USR1 kill signal handler

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script that runs as a service, like this:

```py
import time
import traceback

while True:
    time.sleep(60)

    try:
        main()
    except Exception:
        # Print the traceback, but keep running
        traceback.print_exc()
```

This runs every 60 seconds, and works great. What I want to do is have my code also listen for the `USR1` kill signal, and if it triggers, run main() right away. This way, my code can monitor something for changes periodically, but it can also get informed when a change happened, so it can react right away without waiting for the `time.sleep()` to return.

What I ended up with is this:

```py
from threading import Lock
import signal
import time
import traceback

MAIN_RUNNING = Lock()

def run_main():
    if MAIN_RUNNING.acquire(blocking=False):
        try:
            main()
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
    else:
        print("main() is already running - couldn't lock it")

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, lambda *_: run_main())

while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    run_main()
```

Does that make sense?

Any potential problems I might run into with this?

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I get an error when running your code `NameError: name 'main' is not defined` before the expected messages `main() is already running - couldn't lock it` appear. I think your code is more suited to StackOverflow and not Code Review. Thanks.

Comment: @C.Harley that's because `main` is a stand-in for whatever my code is supposed to do, is irrelevant to the question, and is therefore not defined in the example. My real main function is very large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic code looks fine, but you may encounter one issue if you start doing more complex work.

Signals are handled in a different context to the context your program is normally executing in - the OS can suspend your program at any time, while it's running or not, to run a signal handler which then may execute more code from your program (if it's a signal for your process).

This problem gives rise to the concept of "reentrant functions" which can safely have one thread suspended half way through execution, and have another thread enter it and run - without say, stomping on shared global variables or static allocations. There are surprisingly few reentrant functions in the C standard library, and POSIX libraries - see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html for more information and a list.

Expect seriously weird bugs or crashes if you call non-reentrant functions from the signal handler context.

A safer way of handling this is to have the signal handler set a flag in your program when it's called. A daemon thread in your program can poll this flag and run in your program's regular context, when desired.

Very naïve pseudocode:

```
ShouldRun = False

func HandleSigUsr1:
    ShouldRun = True
    
func HandleSigUsr1Daemon:
    while (1):
        if ShouldRun == True:
            ShouldRUn = False
            run_main()

signal.Signal(SIGUSR1, handleSigUsr1)
```

A slightly more powerful implementation could sleep for a short time (0.001s? 0.01s?) between daemon loops to avoid constantly sucking up CPU time, or poll a file descriptor rather than a variable, to have the OS sleep the daemon until there's new content.

As a final disclaimer, I'm not sure if Python's signal handling library already does something like this under the hood - it seems like the kind of detail a high level language and runtime like Python would try to hide.